# Find the minimal polynomial for differentiation operator of $x\sin x$

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials

I don't really understand how to approach this:

Let $d$ be the differentation operator of the polynomials over R, $V$ is the space of all differentiable functions. Find the minimal polynomial $min_v^d$ with $v=x\sin x$.

So if I'm looking at $v, d(v), d^2(v), d^3(v), ..., d^k(v)$, I need to find the minimal $k$ that's linearly dependent on $v, d(v), ..., d^k(v)$. But how do I do it? I was thinking of using vectors representing the coefficients of $\sin x, \cos x$ or something like that, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: have you actually calculated $dv$, $d^2v$ etc...?

Comment: I did but i'm not sure how to determine linear independence with $sinx+xcosx, -xsinx+2cosx, ..$

Comment: Looks like the derivative of $(A+Bx)\cos x+(C+Dx)\sin x$ is of the same form again. What does that tell you about the vector space spanned by the functions $v, dv, d^2v, d^3v\ldots$?

Comment: To check for linear independence of functions, you may use the Wronskian: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian

Comment: Thanks! I'm still not sure if I checked the linear independence right, so just to verify, is the minimal polynomial $X^4+2X^2+1$?